# What does the model number refer to?

Tags: macos, ios, appletv

There are two different "model numbers" for Apple products.

For example, the Apple TV 4K has:

- MQD22LL/A
- A1842

Which is the "model number" and what is the other number called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**A… is a model number**, referring to the model of device.
**M… is a part number**, referring to a specific configuration of a model.

For example, for devices with various configurations such as whether a device is unlocked and international, the model number will be identical to a US device but the part number will differ.